# how I add string extension to convert string to utf8

Tags: swift, utf-8, extension-methods

I need convert string to utf8 , when I search I got this

```
let str = String(UTF8String: strToDecode.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
```

some people said this add as String extension,
where I should add this? and after that how I can get string with utf8 encode

Answer (score 2):

This is how it should be done if you want to use extension.

```
let str = "1234567890"
    extension String {
    var utf8Array: [UInt8] {
        return Array(utf8)
    }
}

str.utf8Array
```

But I would recommend doing it simply like this

```
let result = [UInt8](str.utf8)
```

Comment: this is work when I print it, but I need use that with api by alamofire library, when I send arabic or speces I have error

Comment: here my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095613/send-arabic-words-and-spaces-to-api-not-work-with-alamofire